# How can I assign all the file names of all subdirectories to a variable with cmake?

Tags: cmake

I'm currently working in a certain directory. How can I assign all file names of all subdirectories to a variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [file](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake-2-8-docs.html#command%3afile) command with the GLOB_RECURSE option:

```
file (GLOB_RECURSE _files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.*")
```

will find all files in the current source directory and its subdirectories and assign it to the variable `_files`.

```
file (GLOB_RECURSE _files "${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/*.cpp")
```

will only return the files with the extension .cpp.